# Excel years/weeks calendar to present machine maintenance periods, VLOOKUP not doing it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have ran into a problem how to visually present machine allocation and maintenance periods on yearly basis. I have a table with data like this:

[image]

and i would need a yearly presentation from this data like this:

[image]

I've tried to use VLOOKUP with IF(AND()) FUNCTIONS, but i think i'm on wrong tracks, because VLOOKUP
returns only first occurrence of an item. So i would need to check in each cell of the table if:

- machine A1-AXX (rows) is in maintenance on that week (column) and year, and return 1 if it is true

I can present this with logic, but cannot come up with excel function for this

- CHECK from data_table for rows where Machine_id = A1 if given week on given year falls between any of planned maintenance start and end times for that machine and return 1 if found, and 0 if not
- SQL for this would be (on week 1 of 2020) `SELECT * FROM data WHERE Machine_id = A1 AND WEEK(Maintenance_start) <= 1 AND WEEK(Maintenance_end) >= 1 AND YEAR(Maintenance_start) = 2020`

How to do this in Excel?

Comment: is the dates  stored as excel data format or it is stored as text ? F2 cell doesn't seem to have a valid year..

Comment: the dates are excel data, F2 is a typo...

Comment: Can you can change all the mtce start/end dates to week numbers ? then do vlookup / index match ...

Comment: Tried to use (for ex in cell C4) `=IF(AND(ISOWEEKNUM(VLOOKUP(B4;range;startdate))<=C3; ISOWEEKNUM(VLOOKUP(B4;range;startdate))>=C3;YEAR(VLOOKUP(B4;range;startdate)) = 2020);1;0)` and also tried with creating extra data columns for dates to weeknumbers. The problem (AFAIK) is that VLOOKUP returns always only the first match of B4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an array formula. 
Formula in sample:

```
{=(SUM(IF(($G2=$A$2:$A$10)*(WEEKNUM(OFFSET($B2;ROW($B$2:$B$10)-ROW($B2);))<=H$1)*(WEEKNUM(OFFSET($C2;ROW($C$2:$C$10)-ROW($C2);))>=H$1);1;0))>0)+0}
```

Array formulas can be entered after typing by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter. The WNS and WNE fields are for testing purposes.

Sample:
[image]

Comment: I will try this, looks promising!